# How to stop Maven build for any jOOQ error?

Tags: maven, jooq

When

```
mvn package
```

is executed in a project that depends on jOOQ (`jooq-codegen-maven:3.7.0`) the build finishes even though the console shows errors.

Is it possible to have the build process stopped when there are jOOQ errors?

The project also uses `maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1` to build the artifact.

Console:

```
[ERROR] Error while fetching enums
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select (...)]; ERRO: Permission denied for schema blabla
    (...)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: Permission denied for schema blabla
    (...)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## EDIT

Stacktrace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< br.com.jooq:jooq-bla >----------------------
[INFO] Building jooq-bla 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.7.0:generate (default) @ jooq-bla ---
[INFO] License parameters       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Database parameters      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   dialect                : POSTGRES
[INFO]   URL                    : jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db
[INFO]   target dir             : /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jOOQ-BLA/workspace/target/generated-sources/jooq
[INFO]   target package         : br.com.jooq
[INFO]   includes               : [.*]
[INFO]   excludes               : []
[INFO]   includeExcludeColumns  : false
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] DefaultGenerator parameters
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   strategy               : class org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy
[INFO]   deprecated             : true
[INFO]   generated annotation   : true
[INFO]   JPA annotations        : false
[INFO]   validation annotations : false
[INFO]   instance fields        : true
[INFO]   records                : true
[INFO]   pojos                  : false
[INFO]   immutable pojos        : false
[INFO]   interfaces             : false
[INFO]   daos                   : false
[INFO]   relations              : true
[INFO]   global references      : true
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Generation remarks       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   none                   
[INFO]                          
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@  @  @  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Thank you for using jOOQ 3.7.0

[INFO] Generating schemata      : Total: 2
[INFO] No schema version is applied for schema public. Regenerating.
[INFO] Generating schema        : Public.java
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Sequences fetched        : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] Tables fetched           : 4 (4 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] UDTs fetched             : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] Generating tables        
[INFO] Synthetic primary keys   : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] Overriding primary keys  : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] Generating table         : AncestraisUnidadeOrganizacional.java [input=ancestrais_unidade_organizacional, output=ancestrais_unidade_organizacional, pk=N/A]
[INFO] ARRAYs fetched           : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[WARNING] SQL exception            : Exception while executing meta query: ERROR: Permission denied for schema bla

Please report this bug here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

select "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumlabel"
from "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"
  join "pg_catalog"."pg_type"
  on "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumtypid" = "pg_catalog"."pg_type".oid
  join "pg_catalog"."pg_namespace"
  on "pg_catalog"."pg_type"."typnamespace" = "pg_catalog"."pg_namespace".oid
where (
  "pg_catalog"."pg_namespace"."nspname" = 'bla'
  and "pg_catalog"."pg_type"."typname" = 'request_action'
)
order by "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumlabel"::"bla"."request_action" asc
[ERROR] Error while fetching enums
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumlabel" from "pg_catalog"."pg_enum" join "pg_catalog"."pg_type" on "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumtypid" = "pg_catalog"."pg_type".oid join "pg_catalog"."pg_namespace" on "pg_catalog"."pg_type"."typnamespace" = "pg_catalog"."pg_namespace".oid where ("pg_catalog"."pg_namespace"."nspname" = ? and "pg_catalog"."pg_type"."typname" = ?) order by "pg_catalog"."pg_enum"."enumlabel"::"bla"."request_action" asc]; ERROR: Permission denied for schema bla
    at org.jooq.impl.Utils.translate (Utils.java:1687)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException (DefaultExecuteContext.java:661)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute (AbstractQuery.java:356)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch (AbstractResultQuery.java:305)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch (AbstractResultQuery.java:369)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch (SelectImpl.java:2615)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.enumLabels (PostgresDatabase.java:603)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.enumLabels (PostgresDatabase.java:591)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.getEnums0 (PostgresDatabase.java:435)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnums (AbstractDatabase.java:763)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnum (AbstractDatabase.java:852)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnum (AbstractDatabase.java:847)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getType (JavaGenerator.java:4514)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType (JavaGenerator.java:4462)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType (JavaGenerator.java:4458)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTable (JavaGenerator.java:2919)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTable (JavaGenerator.java:2869)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTables (JavaGenerator.java:2856)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate (JavaGenerator.java:307)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate (JavaGenerator.java:267)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:434)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:180)
    at org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin.execute (Plugin.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Permission denied for schema bla
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute (QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute (PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags (PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute (PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute (DefaultPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute (AbstractResultQuery.java:262)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute (AbstractQuery.java:342)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch (AbstractResultQuery.java:305)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch (AbstractResultQuery.java:369)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch (SelectImpl.java:2615)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.enumLabels (PostgresDatabase.java:603)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.enumLabels (PostgresDatabase.java:591)
    at org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase.getEnums0 (PostgresDatabase.java:435)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnums (AbstractDatabase.java:763)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnum (AbstractDatabase.java:852)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnum (AbstractDatabase.java:847)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getType (JavaGenerator.java:4514)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType (JavaGenerator.java:4462)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType (JavaGenerator.java:4458)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTable (JavaGenerator.java:2919)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTable (JavaGenerator.java:2869)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateTables (JavaGenerator.java:2856)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate (JavaGenerator.java:307)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate (JavaGenerator.java:267)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:434)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:180)
    at org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin.execute (Plugin.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Generating table         : ArvoreIdentificadorObjeto.java [input=arvore_identificador_objeto, output=arvore_identificador_objeto, pk=N/A]
[INFO] Generating table         : ArvoreIdentificadorObjetoPermissoes.java [input=arvore_identificador_objeto_permissoes, output=arvore_identificador_objeto_permissoes, pk=N/A]
[INFO] Generating table         : ArvoreUnidadeOrganizacional.java [input=arvore_unidade_organizacional, output=arvore_unidade_organizacional, pk=N/A]
[INFO] Tables generated         : Total: 1.995s
[INFO] Generating table references
[INFO] Table refs generated     : Total: 2.001s, +5.668ms
[INFO] Generating Keys          
[INFO] Keys generated           : Total: 2.004s, +2.682ms
[INFO] Generating table records 
[INFO] Generating record        : AncestraisUnidadeOrganizacionalRecord.java
[INFO] Generating record        : ArvoreIdentificadorObjetoRecord.java
[INFO] Generating record        : ArvoreIdentificadorObjetoPermissoesRecord.java
[INFO] Generating record        : ArvoreUnidadeOrganizacionalRecord.java
[INFO] Table records generated  : Total: 2.031s, +27.462ms
[INFO] Routines fetched         : 26 (26 included, 0 excluded)
[INFO] Generating routines and table-valued functions
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_desconto_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 1
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_desconto_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 2
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_desconto_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 3
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_desconto_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 4
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_desconto_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 5
[INFO] Generating routine       : CalculaDescontoSalarioBase.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 1
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 2
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 3
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 4
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object calcula_salario_base holds a column without a name at position 5
[INFO] Generating routine       : CalculaSalarioBase.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : EhDescendenteUnidadeOrganizacional.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : GrantAll.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : GrantAllSchema.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : GrantSelectSchema.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower9.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower1.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower2.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower3.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower4.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower5.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower6.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower7.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object lower holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Lower8.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : RefreshMatViewPermissaoUsuarioIdentificadorObjeto.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : RegistraTelefone.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : RegistraVinculoServidorAposentadoFalecido.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : RegistraVinculoServidorFalecido.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object remove_acentuacao holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : RemoveAcentuacao.java
[INFO] Routines generated       : Total: 2.396s, +364.864ms
[INFO] Removing excess files    
[INFO] GENERATION FINISHED: public: Total: 2.397s, +0.684ms
[INFO] No schema version is applied for schema bla. Regenerating.
[INFO] Generating schema        : Bla.java
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Generating routines and table-valued functions
[INFO] Generating routine       : InscricaoRemovidaFunction.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object ira holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : Ira.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object ira_nao_considerando_reconhecimentos holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : IraNaoConsiderandoReconhecimentos.java
[INFO] Generating routine       : PercentualCreditosAprovados.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object recuperar_total_creditos_curso holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : RecuperarTotalCreditosCurso.java
[WARNING] Missing name             : Object total_creditos_aprovados_matricula holds a column without a name at position 1
[INFO] Generating routine       : TotalCreditosAprovadosMatricula.java
[INFO] Routines generated       : Total: 2.463s, +66.101ms
[INFO] Removing excess files    
[INFO] GENERATION FINISHED: bla: Total: 2.463s, +0.359ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jooq-bla ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jOOQ-BLA/workspace/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jooq-bla ---
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.pom (805 B at 820 B/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-1.8.1.pom (3.5 kB at 13 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.pom (713 B at 2.8 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.pom (710 B at 2.8 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.8.1/plexus-compilers-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.8.1/plexus-compilers-1.8.1.pom (1.3 kB at 5.3 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.jar (20 kB at 52 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar (13 kB at 24 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.jar (5.3 kB at 10.0 kB/s)
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 40 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jOOQ-BLA/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ jooq-bla ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jOOQ-BLA/workspace/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jooq-bla ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ jooq-bla ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ jooq-bla ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jOOQ-BLA/workspace/target/jooq-bla-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: formatting changed

Comment: @LukasEder: I added the complete stacktrace of the Jenkins' pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why such errors don't fail code generation is because in many cases, they are

1. Irrelevant to your particular usage
2. Caused by a bug in the SQL produced by `jOOQ-meta` (but you can recover from the bug and continue working with that version, e.g. when `CHECK` constraints cannot be fetched)

However, it obviously makes sense to be able to opt in to failing the build upon any such exception. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9807

As of jOOQ 3.12, you could work around this limitation in at least two ways:

1. Patch the `AbstractDatabase` class at this line and all similar lines: `at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getEnums (AbstractDatabase.java:763)`. That's where the exception is swallowed and logged.
2. As a hack, implement an `ExecuteListener` that throws an `Error` (instead of an `Exception`) any time an exception like these is encountered, because errors are not caught by the above line in `AbstractDatabase`. You can inject the `ExecuteListener` by subclassing `PostgresDatabase` and overriding `PostgresDatabase.create0()`